# IIS NullReferenceException when deployed but not in Dev Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, nullreferenceexception

I have developed an IIS Application using C# code behind ASPX pages with entity framework for database access. When I run it in the Visual Studio Development Server it works fine but if I either Publish it to IIS or run it on the Local IIS Web Server from Visual Studio (which is pretty much the same as Publishing I guess) I get

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.Hosting.RecyclableCharBuffer.Append(String s) +15
   System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequest.SendUnknownResponseHeader(String name, String value) +93
   System.Web.HttpResponse.WriteHeaders() +233
   System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush) +219
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FinishRequest(HttpWorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context, Exception e) +127
```

This Exception  is thrown after my Home.aspx has finished it's Page Load. Some simple ASPX pages work ok. Setting a NullReferenceException break point just drops into disassembly.

I am stuck for ideas about how to track this issue down. Any thoughts???

Comment: after Page_Load , there are many more Page events till it renders all the controls.

Comment: Have you looked at your webconfig? Does it match what you used on your Dev server? Have you gone into IIS and configured the server? Created the virtual Directory? Is it in the correct AppPool? Tons of things could be wrong here.

Comment: Well, yes I have been trying to get this going all day so I have looked at lots of things. Surely things like web.config are copied over as part of the Publish? My hunch is that it is an incorrect dll version or something on IIS that is ok on Development Server because it is picked up from VS, but how do I track it down?

Comment: what is there in your Page_Load , any MIME type is returned ?

Comment: @khakipuce - Are you using Session variables?

Comment: Yes I am using session variables. There is no mime type set.The page load just checks for a valid user - I am using windows authentication - and populates a GridVeiw from a linq query on a database first Entity Framework query.

Comment: Any more relevant code? The error makes it seem like an uninitialized string is being muted.

Comment: But if it's an uninitialized string why does it work in development but not when published? I have confirmed that the published app can access the database.

Answer (score 2):

Finally tracked this down. Some of out template code in the master page was doing

```
Response.AddHeader("X-UA-Compatible", (String)Application["X-UA-Compatible"]);
```

when Published Application["X-UA-Compatible"] was null.

It's worth knowing that having nulls in Response.AddHeader() causes this kind of problem rather than handling the null more gracefully.